Translation without context
I'm actually reading a novella (Mexican author) for young adults. At a part where two young female characters talking intensly about romantic relationships and don't understand meaning of a word in this context: "consentimiento".

No salía con el para tener una relación, solo quería el consentimiento.

First thought this referred to "consent" in the sense of permision or agreement etc. All translations I've looked at refer to things like sexual consent. But now not sure as it does not work well with the preceding clause, since consent should have existed.
Does "consentimiento" have a translation different to "consent" here?

For clarity - the characters in question did go out; but never maintained a "relationship"

Without more context, I think it may come from the verb "consentir", which among other meanings, mean "mimar", from consentir:


tr. Mimar a los hijos, ser muy indulgente con los niños o con los inferiores.


I'm not sure why the dictionary restricts it to the child, kids or inferiors, but it is used as a synonym of mimar, which means:


tr. Hacer caricias y halagos.
tr. Tratar con excesivo regalo, cariño y condescendencia a alguien, y en especial a los niños.
tr. Favorecer a alguien, tratarlo con mucha consideración.
tr. Tratar algo con especial cuidado y delicadeza.


"Solo quería el consentimiento." sounds a little odd, because it's more natural to say
Solo quería que me consintiera
Reading the surroundings may shed some light on what the meaning of the expression is the correct one.

I agree, without more context it's difficult to understand the complete meaning of the sentence, although jachguate's interpretation seems correct as an alternative to "consent" (which does not have much sense in that construction, by the way)

So can the noun "el consentimiento" in case of question mean "as a treat (or indulgence)" or "to treat / indulge"?

I would say it could mean "I just wanted the coddling" or something like that.

Sometimes the word "consentimiento" could also mean approval, or be able to do something. It sounds like, in this context, she wanted to feel that she can be his partner at any time, but not at that moment specifically.

Not sure I agree- to me the statement is that they did go out, at that time, but not to have a relationship
